# Install Linux without USB or DVD?

Tags: system-installation, crunchbang

I was wondering if there was a way to install Crunchbang on to my spare 1TB partition without using a USB or DVD while booted in Windows? I've Googled this plenty of times, but it usually just comes up for Ubuntu which wouldn't work for Crunchbang.

Comment: Do you want to have Windows and Linux running at the same time, or are do just need to avoid burning a CD/DVD (or USB flash drive)?

Comment: @derobert Only Linux running and to avoid burning CD/DVD or USB

Comment: You could possibly use unetbootin to do this, though you would need to reboot to install Crunchbang so it wouldn't be 'from windows'. Alternatively if all you wanted was to install Crunchbang without using external media, if you have a spare computer you could setup PXE booting.

Comment: I asked a similar question and got this answer, which might work for you if you adapt it for Windows: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78536/29783

Comment: For Red Hat/initial Fedora at least there used to be (haven't looked lately) the option of downloading the packages (or a CD/DVD image) and install from disk. Fedora offers the option of a network install, either using a (very minimal) CD or directly booting and installing over the net (but that requires setting up a server).